# Dequeuing messages from queue from Oracle 10 using cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle10g, cx-oracle, oracle-xe

I have a queue set up named 'ORGS_QUEUE' in which messages are enqueued using a trigger when a record is inserted into a table. The trigger works fine and when i can successfully dequeue messages using sql.

Now i am trying to do this using cx_Oracle and i am using the following code:

```
def dequeue_data():
    TYPE_NAME = "MESSAGE_TYPE"
    QUEUE_NAME = "ORGS_QUEUE"
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("TEST", '123', "localhost/xe")
    queue_type = connection.gettype(TYPE_NAME)
    queue = connection.queue(QUEUE_NAME, queue_type)
    queue.deqOptions.wait = cx_Oracle.DEQ_NO_WAIT
    queue.deqOptions.visibility = cx_Oracle.DEQ_IMMEDIATE
    msg = queue.deqOne()
    connection.commit()
    xref, data = msg.payload.XREF, msg.payload.REC_DATA
    print xref, data
```

On runnign this code i get error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dequeue_test.py", line 31, in <module>
    dequeue_data()
  File "/home/user/dequeue_test.py", line 13, in dequeue_data
    msg = queue.deqOne()
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 24 Serial number: 49
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the database 10g? What version is the client? 10g is rather old and a newer version of the database should be used if at all possible -- preferably 19g since that is a long-term release.

Comment: yes the database is 10g. I would myself prefer using 19g but currently i am stuck with 10g.